# Jaeger integration Effort in Microservices in nodejs

Tags: microservices, opentracing, jaeger

I am analysing at a very hight level how much effort would it be for jaeger integration in nodejs microservices.

Does it require code changes or only deployment. and if code changes is required, is code changes needed in first service (i.e. api-gateway) or all the services need to have code changes.

I would really appreciate if someone can give a rough idea of tasks and effort.

Answer (score 0):

Great question and a very popular one too. In short, yes, code changes are required. Not just in one service but in all the services that a request will go through. You need to instrument all services to get continuous traces that will be able to tell you the story of a request as it travels through the system.